# In Onion Structure, can an infrastructure service call another infrastructure service?

Tags: onion-architecture

For example, there are two services in the infrastructure layer:

1. `Contact`, which is an Elasticesearch service.
2. `PhoneNumber` which is a SQL service.

The `Contact` service needs to get each contact's phone number and return to its caller, so it needs to call the `PhoneNumber` service.

I am wondering if `Contact` can call `PhoneNumber` directly? They are both in the infrastructure layer.

Or, should I let `Contact` return to the service in the **domain** layer first, then let the domain layer service call `PhoneNumber`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that in infrastructure, using a service in another service isn't right pattern, because all services in this layer should be third party services and there should be no relation between them in our infrastructure layer.

**Application layer** is responsible for fetching data from infrastructure services.
For instance, in this layer, below method could be implemented

```
List<string> GetPhoneNumbers(string contactName)
{
  var phoneNumbers = new List<string>();

  var contacts = _contactService.GetContacts(contactName);
  foreach(var contact in contacts)
  {
    var phoneNumber = _phoneService.GetPhoneNumber(contact)
    phoneNumbers.Add(phoneNumber);
  }    
  return phoneNumbers;
}
```

`_contactService` along with `_phoneService` are the two services in infrastructure layer. The betters name for them would be `_contactRepository` and `_phoneRepository` if you use Repository pattern.